# Method to fake 3d in 2d top down game

Tags: animation, 2.5d, visualization

I'm relatively new to game development and its terminology and I was wondering how to achieve the effect that is being used on the main character in this game:

http://youtu.be/XK7whzmywno?t=2m38s

To me, it looks like they animated at least 32 directions.
How do they do this? Is it simply creating 2-3 frames for each direction and animation or is there somekind of skewing/distortion technique involved?

Comment: It seems to me like they just have one frame for each of the 32 directions. The walk animation alternates between the two frames left and right from the direction the character is walking to.

Comment: This method was also used to fake 3d in 3d games when they were still new. The original Doom rendered images of each frame of animation for its creatures from 8 different directions. The map was in 3d, but all the monsters were 2d images.